# How to retry file transfer using transferId (IBM MQ fte)

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

We've been transferring files from one folder to another using CNTFTEAgent. But sometimes source file appears to be locked in a source folder (mq Explorer says that "file is not found" but it does exist though), so that transferring becomes as "failed".
We decided to use "exits" for retrying such failed tranfers. 
The last fired "exit" is SourceTransferEndExit, but it does not contain information about file and filspace where file should be put to.
But it contains transferId. So my question is - how to retry transferring attemption using java API, or is it possible to do that somehow, if we know only transferId?

Such information can be found in TransferMetaInfo and looks like this -

```
com.ibm.wmqfte.TransferId => 414d5120434e54465445514d47522020ce34465321038a03
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retry using ant, 'rcproperty' property hold transfer status. If transfer status is not '0' then retry.